# how to fetch uploaded file from wp-content/uploads to a webpage

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used the below code in function.php to fetch the uploaded file from wp-content/uploads.File is successfully uploaded to the wp-content/uploads.

I have tried the below mentioned code to download/view the file in my webpage. But that doesn't seems to be working.

```
function load_query_list()
{
    if( is_page( 'query-list-admin-area' ) )
    {
    global $wpdb;   
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM tbl_Query " );
        if(!empty($results))  
        {   
            echo "<table width='50%' border='0' align='center' style='margin:30px;color:black'>"; 
            echo"<thead><tr><th>Email</th><th>QuerNo</th><th>Query</th><th>Status</th><th>FileName</th><th>View</th></tr></thead>";
            foreach ( $results as $res ) 
            {

            echo "<tr><td>".$res->Email."</td><td>".$res->QueryNo."</td><td>".$res->Query."</td><td>".$res->Reply."</td><td>".$res->fname."</td><td><a href=/home/u992815795/domains/taxhomes.in/public_html/wp-content/uploads/".$res->fname.">View File</a></td></tr>";

            }
        }
    }            
}
```

I want to view/download the uploaded file from wp-content/uploads while clicking the viewFile hyperlink in mycode.

Comment: How are you uploading the file? Every uploaded file has a permalink, why not just use that instead of custom db query?

Comment: Below code is used to upload the file.

Comment: if(isset($_FILES["uploadfile"]) && $_FILES["uploadfile"]["error"] == 0)
 { $target_dir = "/home/u992815795/domains/taxhomes.in/public_html/wp-content/uploads/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]);
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
  {
       // echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
     } 
else 
  {   
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
     }
  
 }

Comment: how to use thebpermalink to fetch the file